# Geting values by timestamp to find percent change. Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find the precent change in two values from a mysql database.

I have a cron job set up to insert values approximately every hour..

Each value has a unix timestamp associated with it and I want to get the previous days(~24hrs) value and compare with the current one to get percent increase or decrease.

Table looks like this:

```
+-----+----+
|value|time|
+-----+----+
```

Comment: Will there always be a value **exactly** 24 hours before. And what about the values for the first day? Then there won't be a value for the day before. So what should happen there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to sum the values from day 1 and day 2, yes?  This would give you the change between readings by calendar day.

```
SELECT t1.time, (sum(t1.value) - sum(t2.value))
from table t1, table t2
where t1.time>t2.time
and t1.time = t2.time + (60 * 60 * 24)
group by date(from_unixtime(t1.time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this assuming that there are exact matches from the previous day:

```
SELECT T1.time, (T1.value - T2.value) * 100 / T2.value AS percent_change
FROM yourtable T1
JOIN yourtable T2
ON T1.time = T2.time + (60 * 60 * 24) --# seconds in a day
WHERE T1.time > ....
```